# wget vbulletin forum with exclude pages & pictures

Tags: wget

I try to download an vbulletin forum using

```
wget -r -p -k -e robots=off http://www.example.com/vb/
```

the about command  work fine but i don't want to download the whole site
can i exclude ( pictures,icons and some pages like register.php and member.php)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can exclude pictures, icons by adding `... -R jpg,jpeg,png,gif,bmp,ico ...`

Comment: ok , thanks , work i also add exclude paths and domains as well.

Comment: `--exclude-domains domain-list` `--include-directories=list` `--exclude-directories=list` the lists to be put here are comma separated lists.. i.e. /people,/cgi-bin